# D3.js exit strange behavior

Tags: javascript, html, web, d3.js, visualization

I am learning D3.js and have some questions about the exit() funcion. Look at the sample code below

```
<html>

<head>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <h1>Hello, World!</h1>
    <p>Test of selection of D3.js</p>
    <p>Test of selection of D3.js</p>
    <p>Test of selection of D3.js</p>
    <p>Test of selection of D3.js</p>
    <p>Test of selection of D3.js</p>
    <p>Test of selection of D3.js</p>
    <p>Test of selection of D3.js</p>


    <script>
        var p = d3.selectAll("p");


        p.data([13,17,21,25])            
         .exit()
         .remove();

         p.style("font-size", function(d) { return d+"px";});


    </script>


</body>

<html>
```

Basically, I have 7 elements with p tab. The code provide 4 data items, .exit().remove() removes the 7-4 = 3 extra p elements. The size of the 4 elements are set after that. This works.

However, according to Mike Bosock's tutotiral http://mbostock.github.io/d3/tutorial/circle.html, the "Destroying Elements" part

```
p.data([13,17,21,25]);
p.exit().remove();
```

Should work as well. But it doesn't.

Any one know what is wrong with that part? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Note this part of his example:

```
var circle = svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data([32, 57]);
```

Then:

```
circle.exit().remove();
```

In your case you're trying to run `.exit().remove()` on the p variable rather than on the data in it. In his example, he's calling it on the data attached to the circle.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var p = d3.selectAll("p");
p = p.data([13,17,21,25]);
p.exit().remove();
```

`selectAll()` is a selector as is `selectAll().data().exit()`